# Pandas DataFrame: Convert Integer time hh:mm

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame which contains

```
 dep_time   sched_dep_time
0   517.0   515
1   533.0   529
2   0.0     0.0
3   544.0   545
4   1.0     101
```

I want it to be in 5:17 , 5:15 as departure and scheduled departure times, NaN are filled with 0's also 1.0 indicates departure at 1:00 
Tried following

```
flight_data['dep_time']=flight_data['dep_time'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: 
                        pd.to_timedelta(x[:-2] + x[-2:]+':00'))
```

Value Error :expecting hh:mm:ss format, received: 21 days 13:00:00.000000000:00
I am even not sure of how dep_time like 0,1,2.. should be converted. Thank you and appreciate your help

Comment: What is your raw data? Because your current data may cause confusion. For example, should I interpret `101` as `1:01` OR as `10:01`?

Comment: It should be interpreted as 1:01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`
- `fillna(0)`
- `pd.to_timedelta`

---

```
d1 = pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), errors='coerce').fillna(0)
(pd.to_timedelta(d1 // 100, unit='T') +
 pd.to_timedelta(d1 % 100, unit='S')).unstack()

  dep_time sched_dep_time
0 00:05:17       00:05:15
1 00:05:33       00:05:29
2 00:00:00       00:00:00
3 00:05:44       00:05:45
4 00:00:01       00:01:01
```